# Add single quotes around a word in an excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, single-quotes

Currently the text in a cell looks like this-

> UPDATE A SET group_name = B WHERE group_ID = C;

Formula used for this is-

```
="UPDATE "&$N$1&" SET "&$N$2&" = "&TEXT($B2,"MM/DD/YY")&"WHERE "&$N$3&" = "&$E2&";"
```

I want to add single quotes around B here so that it looks like this-

> UPDATE A SET group_name = 'B' WHERE group_ID = C;

How do I achieve this by tweaking the above mentioned formula?

Comment: Add the `'`s to the surrounding string constants, ie `" = '` and `"' WHERE "`

Comment: Or; add the single quotes inside `TEXT()` >> `"'MM/DD/YY'"`

Answer (score 1):

As commented few methods here. All following formulas should work for you.

```
="UPDATE "&$N$1&" SET "&$N$2&" = "&TEXT($B2,"'MM/DD/YY'")&" WHERE "&$N$3&" = "&$E2&";"
="UPDATE "&$N$1&" SET "&$N$2&" = '"&TEXT($B2,"MM/DD/YY")&"' WHERE "&$N$3&" = "&$E2&";"
="UPDATE "&$N$1&" SET "&$N$2&" = "& CHAR(39) & TEXT($B2,"MM/DD/YY") & CHAR(39) & " WHERE "&$N$3&" = "&$E2&";"
```